# how upgrade rvm and ruby version inside a production server

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-3.2, rvm

I have a production server with nginx and `ruby 1.9.3p125 (2012-02-16 revision 34643)`.

I have taken a look to http://www.ruby-lang.org/en/news/2012/11/09/ruby-1-9-3-p327-is-released/ and I want upgrade to `ruby-1-9-3-p327` to fix security bugs.

**Where can I find a manual or tutorial to upgrade ruby version and my rvm version?**

Thank you

Comment: I've done this a couple of times. One thing to look out for, esp. when using nginx + Passenger Phusion is that if you upgrade Ruby or passenger gem then you'll have to recompile nginx + passenger.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

First upgrade RVM:

```
rvm get stable
```

Then upgrade installed Ruby:

```
rvm upgrade ruby-1.9.3-p125 ruby-1.9.3-p327
```

https://rvm.io/rubies/upgrading/

Comment: Would this preserve ruby executable path, gem executable, bundle, etc? I have exactly the same issue, but I do have a bunch of deployment scripts and stuff that have Ruby base path hard-coded.

Comment: Yes, it will migrate gemsets, wrappers, aliases and environment files.

Comment: OP is asking about a production server - is this a valid approach for that? Seems a bit scary to do an in-place upgrade beneath running apps.

Comment: Abe Voelker, that's what I was thinking too. I'd probably install newer build of Ruby 1.9.3 alongside that old one and then switch over paths in deployment scripts, etc. If I do that - I'll have a way to quickly back out that upgrade if something goes wrong.

Comment: It's a patch release and upgrading shouldn't be a problem. A few notes: 1. pay attention to prompt messages    2. migrating gemsets/gems can take a while if you've a lot of gems. Maybe better to avoid migration and install them with next deploy.    3. i can't guarantee a zero downtime: you will need to restart your app server afterwards. It can take a few minutes.

Answer (score 1):

If your app cannot suffer any downtime, it is wise to duplicate your production environment locally, performing the upgrade through rvm as NARKOZ points out and then running your tests to ensure everything still works as expected.

You can use something like VirtualBox to keep the clone separate from your dev environment.

Once you're confident everything works, then do the upgrade. I'd even recommend taking a snapshot backup of your server before proceeding.

Good Luck.